# Perl extracting multiple values out of thousands of Excel Files and write each dataset into txt file

Tags: perl, win32ole

I am using **Perl 5.24.3** on **Windows 7** with **Strawberry Perl**.
I am currently writing a script that searches thousands of Excel files for certain values in the same folder. These values are extracted/read from each Excel file and saved in their corresponding variables.
After that, I want to write the variable values into a .txt file.

My problem is that the perl script crashes at Excel file 400ish.
I cannot run it when using **use strict** but it will run if I leave it out.
Unfortunately not till the end. How can I optimize my script so it won't crash?
How do I need to change my code so that I can run the script WITH **use strict**?

**use diagnostics** returns the following:

```
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at auswertungLieferscheine.pl line 112(#1), line 117, 122, 127, ...
```

*Here is the code:*

```
#use strict;
#use warnings "all";
use Cwd 'abs_path';
use Win32::OLE;
#use diagnostics;

lager();

sub lager
{
    my @xlsm;
    my $strGebLS = "Z:\\User\\Projekte\\Fertigung\\Lieferscheintool\\lieferschein_lager\\bearbeitete Lieferscheine\\gebuchte Lieferscheine\\";
    chdir $strGebLS;

    opendir(DIR, $strGebLS) or die $!;

    while(my $lieferschein = readdir(DIR))
    {   
        next if ($lieferschein !~ m/2018\.xlsm$/);
        push(@xlsm, $lieferschein);
    }
    closedir(DIR);

    my $excel = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', 'Quit') or die $!;
    $excel->{'DisplayAlerts'} = 0;
    $excel->{'Visible'} = 0;

    foreach my $lsDatei(@xlsm)
    {   
    my $absPfad = abs_path("$lsDatei") or die "Fehler: Die Datei $lsDatei wurde nicht gefunden\n";
        my $arbeitsmappe = $excel->Workbooks->Open($absPfad, {
            'ReadOnly' => 1,
            'IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended' => 1
          });
        my $sheet = $arbeitsmappe->Worksheets("LieferscheinBauleitung");

        # THESE VALUES ARE ALWAYS IN THE SAME CELL OR PREDEFINED IF CELLS EMPTY!
        my $lagerort = "Lager";
        my $lsNr = $sheet->Range("C5")->{Value};
        my $status = "gebucht";
        my $bv = $sheet->Range("C7")->{Value};
        my $hv = $sheet->Range("G7")->{Value};
        my $grund = "Kein Anforderungsgrund";
        my $besteller = "Kein Besteller";
        my $abholer = "Kein Abholer";
        my $bezeichnung ="Keine Bezeichnung";
        my $menge = "0";
        my $einzelpreis = "0.0";
        my $summe = "0.0";

        #THESE VALUES ARE IN DIFFERENT CELLS 
#BUT ALWAYS IN 1 out of 2 POSSIBLE COLUMNS! 
#THAT IS WHY I AM USING A FOR LOOP HERE... 
#THE IF LINES RETURN UNDECLARED WARNINGS FOR VARIABLES AND I DONT KNOW WHY! WHY?! #$sheet and $zeile are both defined, aren't they?!
        for (my $zeile=4; $zeile<=25;$zeile++)
        {           
            if($sheet->Range("G" . $zeile)->{Value} eq "Grund")
            {
                $grund = $sheet->Range("G" . $zeile + 2)->{Value};
            }

            if($sheet->Range("A" . $zeile)->{Value} eq "Anforderungsgrund")
            {
                $grund = $sheet->Range("C" . $zeile)->{Value};
            }

            if($sheet->Range("A" . $zeile)->{Value} eq "Besteller")
            {
                $besteller = $sheet->Range("C" . $zeile)->{Value};  
            }

            if($sheet->Range("A" . $zeile)->{Value} eq "Abholer")
            {
                $abholer = $sheet->Range("C" . $zeile)->{Value};
            }   

            if($sheet->Range("B" . $zeile)->{Value} eq "Bezeichnung")
            {
                $bezeichnung = $sheet->Range("B" . ($zeile + 2))->{Value};
            }
            if($sheet->Range("A" . $zeile)->{Value} eq "Menge")
            {
                $menge = $sheet->Range("A" . ($zeile + 2))->{Value};
            }
            if($sheet->Range("H" . $zeile)->{Value} eq "Einzelpreis")
            {
                $einzelpreis = $sheet->Range("H" . ($zeile + 2))->{Value};
            }
            if($sheet->Range("I" . $zeile)->{Value} eq "Summe")
            {
                $summe = $sheet->Range("I" . ($zeile + 2))->{Value};
            }       
        }   
        $arbeitsmappe->Close();
        $excel->Quit();

        if($besteller eq "") 
        {
            $besteller = "Kein Besteller";
        }
        if($abholer eq "")
        {
            $abholer = "Kein Abholer";
        }
        if($grund eq "")
        {
            $grund = "Kein Anforderungsgrund";
        }

        # WRITE VALUES IN VARIABLES INTO TXT-FILE

        if(substr($lsDatei, -9, 4) eq "2018")
        {       
            local $auswertung = "auswertungLieferscheine_2018.txt";     
            local $auswertungPfad = "Z:\\User\\Projekte\\Fertigung\\Lieferscheintool\\lieferschein_auswertung\\$auswertung";
            local $data = $lagerort . "\t" . $lsNr . "\t" . $status . "\t" . $bv . "\t" . $hv . "\t" . $grund . "\t" . $besteller . "\t" . $abholer . "\t" . $bezeichnung . "\t" . $menge . "\t" . $einzelpreis . "\t" . $summe . "\n";
            open(my $fh, '>>', $auswertungPfad) or die $!;

            # PRINT DATASET INTO TXT FILE               
            print $fh $data;
            close $fh;
        }
    }   
}
```

The warnings occur in the for-loop where it says if($sheet....eq "something"). Alle if lines are concerned. Any solutions?

Comment: What happens if you add `use strict`? Also, check the cell in the problematic file, it probably doesn't exist or is empty.

Comment: @choroba: Then the script exits immediately.I dont know which of these thousands of excel files is the problematic one. How can I find out which one it is? I think the cause for the script to crash is more like a performance issue or an overflow at some point.

Comment: It doesn't just "exit immediately", it complains about undeclared variables: `Global symbol "$auswertung" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $auswertung"?) at try.pl line 114.`, etc. Why are you using `local` at all?

Comment: Does it exit immediately without any error messages? What's the exit status? If you want to know what file is being processed, just `print` its name to STDOUT or STDERR.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "crash"? What are the symptoms? (Also, "optimizing" won't fix a crash.)

Comment: @melpomene and choroba: I am on Windows 7, maybe that is why it exits without showing anything. It just closes perl.exe after executing the script. Well, the script just exits at excel file 403 out of 2000. I changed local to my and ran the script again, exits at the same point again. By crash I mean the perl.exe console window closes/exits. The file is no different from all others. How can I find out the exit status?

Comment: I'm also on Windows 7. Why don't you run `cmd` and start the script from an existing console window? That way it doesn't close when the script exits.

Comment: @melpomene: I start the script with auswertungLieferscheine.cmd. With the following command in it: start /min perl auswertungLieferscheine.pl >> perl.log 2>&1 & When the script "exits", the log file is empty.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work. As far as I can tell, that redirects the output of `start` to `perl.log`, but the perl script itself runs in a new window and that's where its output goes. Try removing the `start /min` part so we have a change of figuring out what's going on.

Comment: @melpomene: The script exits because of this error: "Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at auswertungLieferscheine.pl line 115. Line 115 is this: $grund = $sheet->Range("G" . $zeile + 2)->{Value}; BUT why does the script ignore that error for 402 lines and suddenly it doesn't accept it? I removed files 403 and 404 for testing. But the next excel file 405 gets the same error and provokes a script exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible bug:

```
$grund = $sheet->Range("G" . $zeile + 2)->{Value};
```

makes no sense. The `.` and `+` operators have the same precedence (and are left associative), so `"G" . $zeile + 2` parses as `("G" . $zeile) + 2`. `"G..."` converted to a number is `0` (and produces a warning), so this effectively calls `$sheet->Range(2)`.

You probably want

```
$grund = $sheet->Range("G" . ($zeile + 2))->{Value};
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you, the script now properly runs till the end. It takes 10 minutes though. Is there a way to optimize this. What could I change in my code to make it go faster?